# computed column making the select query to run slow

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, computed-column

We are creating indexes, as per the requirements, on one server and copying all the indexes to the other servers. All servers have similar objects & schema but different resource configuration values.

We have an issue where a query that joins 4 views is completing on one server but the same query is taking 4 minutes on the other server. If I take out the computed column from the select list it is completing in 4 seconds.

The two execution plans are quite different.

1)  Is this a good plan to copy the indexes blindly where SQL is choosing different execution plans?

2) I have also tried to create the index on the computed column on the base table, still no luck, any further suggestions? ( We can’t create an index on views for some reason.)

Comment: How complex is the computed column? For example, does it have functions, or do complex math?

Comment: Are your statistics up to date? Is the computed column persisting data?

Comment: its a simple sum (Qnty)*-1

Comment: yes Peter,its persisting ,but not heavily, we are creating this column in a view and trying to join this view with other views

Comment: Add more details. The description (*"I have also tried to create the index on the computed column on the base table, still no luck,.."*) doesn't match with your comments (*"the computed column is a simple sum (Qnty)*"*)

Comment: The plans differ between servers. Understanding why will help.

Answer (score 3):

"Is this a good plan to copy the indexes." Indexes exist to improve the response time of read operations. Those operations arise from the workload. If the workload differs, the indexes should differ, too.

For example, it is not uncommon to have one server handle the OLTP activity and replicate the data to a second server where analytic queries are processed. The first server's work will be mostly single row lookups. The second's range scans and aggregates. In this case having different indexes on each server makes good sense. If *all* indexes were on both servers there would be additional, unnecessary work to do during writes and maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a computed creates a *virtual* column, still computed at runtime for every row selected.

What you need is a computed **persisted** column, which is computed at insert time and stored physically in the table:

```
[ComputedColumn] 
   AS (dbo.Function(column)) PERSISTED
```

*Note: Persisted columns are calculated when the expressions they are calculated from are changed.*

**More Useful information in this article:**

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104359/Computed-Columns-Index-and-Performance

Answer (score -1):

I would try persisting the computed column. If you do this the cost of computing the column will be incurred on writes, persisted, and then it won't slow down reads.